# LINQ Column Attribute not found

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am a beginner in LINQ.

I am using .NET 3.5. and VS 2008.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Data.Linq.Provider;

namespace LINQ_to_SQL_Test
{
    [Table(Name="Person")]
    public class Person
    {
        [Column(Name="ID", Storage="_ID", DbType="IS NOT NULL IDENTITY", Id=true, AutoGen=true)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int IDRole { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The program was unable to find the definitions for `Id` and `AutoGen` in Column attribute.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "[t]he program" I am assuming that you are referring to a C# compiler, and probably `csc` installed with Visual Studio 2008.

The syntax that you are using to set the properties of the [`ColumnAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute_members.aspx) is outdated; I believe that syntax was correct when LINQ was released as a CTP. The correct syntax now is:

```
[Column
    (
    Name="ID",
    Storage="_ID",
    DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY",
    IsPrimaryKey=true,
    IsDbGenerated=true
    )
]
```

That is, `Id` has been replaced by `IsPrimaryKey` and `AutoGen` has been replaced by `IsDbGenerated`.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such properties in `ColumnAttribute`. For `Id`, what you're looking for is probably `IsPrimaryKey`. Regarding `AutoGen`, I have no idea what it's supposed to mean in that context...

EDIT: OK, I see what you mean by `AutoGen`... I think the correct property is `IsDbGenerated`